# Adding external web page content to site feed

Tags: embed, external

I want to add a facebook-like "Wall" to my site, but to make it useful, I want members to be able to enter an external web site URL just like facebook, Linkedin and others do, and I need my site to extract a thumb and page description and display it in the member's feed on their wall.  I know facebook tries to use OG tags, and I am not quite sure how LinkedIn and others do it, so my question is:

Are there any PHP or javascript libraries out there to grab, interpret and return the most likely image/description for any random web URL so that I can display that on the member's "wall" wthin my site?  I have seen that there are plenty of RSS feed libraries, but I want it to work with any random web page and have it go to work as soon as the member clicks on the "Post" button to add it to their wall.

I know facebook does it immediately when a URL is added to a post, even before the post is published, but I don't need it to work that immediately.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend trying out [embed.ly](http://embed.ly/). You didn't mention what type of platform you are using, but embed.ly has plugins for Wordpress, Joomla and Drupal, as well as developer code for javascript/jQuery, php, and a couple other languages. You can view it all here: http://embed.ly/docs.

You'll need to sign up for an API key, there is a free version, and if you need to embed more than 10,000 links a month you can start paying.

On a WordPress site I'm developing right now (not open to public, sorry!), I had a similar problem where I need to allow users writing posts or managing the home page to enter a link of just about anything, from static web pages to blog articles to videos.

I followed the instructions on the tutorial page and the functionality I needed was there. -- looks like I don't have enough reputation to post more than one link, but the path is
/docs/tutorials/jquery in the embed.ly site.